# Equality symbol and infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have this equation

$dA=f(x)\,dx,$  ($A$ is an area and $dx$ an infinitesimal length)

and it's probably incorrect since I should use $\approx $ in place of $=$.

But why?

Comment: What do you mean by infinitesimal? That looks like an expression of the differential of some function $A = A(x)$.

Comment: I found it [here](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/8_12.pdf)

Comment: Something like $\Delta A \approx f(x) \ \Delta x$ would be correct. In the limit $\Delta x \to 0$ the expression becomes $dA=f(x) \ dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually should use $=\,$, like you have, and not $\approx\,$, because the LHS differential $dA$ is *defined* by the equation you have there. Remember that an infinitesimal is simply a variable, in its fundamental mathematical nature.